# simplify for loop and if statement with list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am looking to simplify the below with list comprehension:

```
for contract in response:
        if contract['symbol'] == symbol:
            price = contract['lastPrice']
```

I have come up with:

```
[contract for contract in response if contract['symbol'] == symbol]:
        price = contract['lastPrice']
```

But I am not sure with this syntax is not correct.

Comment: I don't think you need to simplify this. It's pretty clear and readable as it is.

Comment: That syntax is totally wrong; I'm not sure why you're surprised that it's incorrect. Please review your instructional materials.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I am not surprised, I know its not correct. I am asking why it is incorrect and looking for how to fix it

Comment: Review your instructional materials regarding comprehensions. Your attempt demonstrates some fundamental misunderstandings - for example, comprehensions are expressions, not compound statements. You really do need to just go back and carefully read through everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go;

```
price = [contract["lastPrice"] for contract in response if contract["symbol"] == symbol]

print(price)
```

Comprehensions are not compound block of code in python but simply expressions which define a particular for loop in a single line of code. As your question is regarding list comprehension, list comprehension is a way of expressing a lop (with or without some condition) in the form of an expression which returns a list as result.
You can also get a dict() as result by using dictionary comprehension.

**EDIT**:
If this is answer to your question, mark this as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Your code is completely wrong. Comprehension doesn't work like that. You are using them like a loop, using colon, indentation but actually this whole thing goes in just a single line with in the brackets. You should learn more about them.

Comment: In OP's non-comprehension code, `price` is presumably a number. In your code, it is a list. OP didn't post enough of their code for me to say for sure what they're doing with it, but I'd say your code most likely doesn't do it.

Comment: I am not behind what is price but how comprehension works. That is what i wanted to show him in the answer.

Comment: And list comprehension returns a list.

Comment: Well, you didn't explain anything about comprehensions, so I don't think you showed anything in that regard. And I know list comprehensions produce a list; that's why I specifically said as much in a specific criticism of this code.

Comment: Edited my answer. Hope you are satisfied now. Thanks!